# react I want to change the style in the props I pass

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am using react and styled-components.
I want to apply the style defined in the dataList when I pass the page name (home,group) to the body component as a props.
I would like to apply the home style of dataList to the box when home is passed in props, and the group style of dataList to the box when group is passed.

I tried to implement it in my own way, but an error occurs at the dataList location.

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-leaf-x6erk?file=/src/Body.tsx:0-757)

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

type Props = {
  type: "home" | "group";
};

export const Body: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, type }) => {
  const dataList = {
    home: {
      gridTemplateAreas: 'header''body',
      gridTemplateRows: 30px calc(100vh - 100px),
      padding: 30
    },
    group: {
      gridTemplateAreas: 'header''menu''body',
      gridTemplateRows: 30px calc(100vh - 70px),
      padding: 30
    }
  };
  const data = dataList[type];
  return <Box props={data}>{children}</Box>;
};

const Box = styled.div<{ props: any }>`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: ${(props) => props.gridTemplateAreas};
  grid-template-rows: ${(props) => props.gridTemplateRows};
  padding-left: ${(props) => props.padding};
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `data` as props in `Box` component. It would be like this:

```
const data = dataList[type];
return <Box {...data}>{children}</Box>;
```

Here is working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-fire-7soy9?file=/src/Body.tsx:458-528

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need to solve the error in dataList.

Comment: Its happening because you are not defining css correctly.

Comment: I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: which style you want to add?